# Contact Form 7 issue with drop down menu spacing

Tags: html, css, wordpress, forms

In this Contact Form 7 form there's a ~32px gap under the select fields: Years in Business, and Annual Revenue. I want to evenly space the fields using CSS but I've been unable to deal with this gap under the select fields, then space all the fields evenly. Please see the attached picture and source code below and recommend how fix the problem. Thanks for your help.

[image: form image]

```html
<form action="/sandbox/pipeline/overview/?preview_id=31&#038;preview_nonce=b4447e0d19&#038;_thumbnail_id=-1&#038;preview=true#wpcf7-f11144-p31-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate">
<div style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="11144" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="5.0.1" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="en_US" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f11144-p31-o1" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_container_post" value="31" />
</div>
<p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap full-name"><input type="text" name="full-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Full Name*" /></span><br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap email"><input type="email" name="email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Email*" /></span><br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap phone"><input type="tel" name="phone" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-tel wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-tel" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Phone*" /></span><br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap zipcode"><input type="text" name="zipcode" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Zip Code*" /></span><br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap company"><input type="text" name="company" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Company Name*" /></span><br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap salespeople"><input type="text" name="salespeople" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Number of Salespeople*" /></span><br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap revenue"><select name="revenue" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"><option value="">Annual Revenue*</option><option value="$1 Million - $5 Million">$1 Million - $5 Million</option><option value="$5 Million - $20 Million">$5 Million - $20 Million</option><option value="$20 Million and Above">$20 Million and Above</option></select></span><br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap years"><select name="years" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"><option value="">Years in Business*</option><option value="0-4 Years">0-4 Years</option><option value="5-10 Years">5-10 Years</option><option value="10+ Years">10+ Years</option></select></span><br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap message"><textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Message"></textarea></span><br />
<input type="submit" value="CONTACT US" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" /></p>
<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div></form>
```

UPDATED FORM IMAGE

[image: UPDATED FORM IMAGE]

Comment: Maybe also provide actual CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to add custom CSS like this (hope it helps because we are missing your CSS so can't tell what's going on and what style is overriding it really, but span is not a block element by default so margin will not affect it at that point unless you define `display:block` your margin will work)

```
.wpcf7-form-control-wrap {
    margin-bottom:10px!important;
    display:block!important;
}
```

Comment: That made a difference. Equal field spacing but 10px plus 32px between all fields now. 

I added an update picture of the form above and links to the CSS's at the bottom of the post above.

Comment: Then just either decrease 10px to something like -10px or something you like, but I also wonder now why there is this `<br />` at the end of each span. Who made this HTML? I would just delete that completely, no need for it anyways. Just give the span proper stylings.

Comment: Prefect. Negative px did the trick. Thanks! BTW, the <br /> in the html is coming from the Contact Form 7 plugin. Negative px for me a better fix than editing the php from CF7. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Create a style or override existing one i.e (wpcf7-form-control-wrap). Give it a margin bottom and use !important to override the existing space.

Comment: I tried:

.wpcf7-form-control-wrap {
      margin-bottom: 10px !important; 
}

but there was no change to the form.